# How to load ModelRenderable.builder() with multiple model?

Tags: android, arcore

I'm not sure how to load model into array for below code. All i can do it load a single model in a single `ModelRenderable.builder()`. but not for multiple model in same `ModelRenderable.builder()`. I appreciate if any one can help me with that.

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
    .setSource(this, Uri.parse("https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/3dmodels/andy.sfb") )
        .setRegistryId(1)
    .build()
    .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
    .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
          Toast toast =
              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
          return null;
        });
  ModelRenderable.builder()
          .setSource(this, Uri.parse("https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/3dmodels/scene.sfb") )

          .build()
          .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable1 = renderable)
          .exceptionally(
                  throwable -> {
                      Toast toast =
                              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                      toast.show();
                      return null;
                  });
  ModelRenderable.builder()
          .setSource(this, Uri.parse("https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/3dmodels/shoes.sfb"))

          .build()
          .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable2 = renderable)
          .exceptionally(
                  throwable -> {
                      Toast toast =
                              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                      toast.show();
                      return null;
                  });
```

here andyrenderable is called to load into an anchor

```
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        andy.setParent(anchorNode);
        andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);

        andy.select();
```

what i can do is , i can load model from Uri but i need to load model in same `ModelRenderable.builder()` as an array for other models too

Comment: Help me to undestand better. Why you wanna load more models in the same builder? What result are you expecting? Why not call this functions in loop?

Comment: sorry my bad. I fixed this issue. Other thing is can we do something with this ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this,"url") with custom texture ?

Comment: Sorry @Rikesh I still didn't know why you wanna load more models in the same builder. What are you expecting to see in your screen?

Comment: i want to change multiple texture inside same builder. @canat

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [sceneform solarsystem sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/SolarActivity.java), my untested solution would be:

```
String[] uris = {
  "https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/3dmodels/andy.sfb",
  ...
  "https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/3dmodels/shoes.sfb"
};
CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable>[] mrs = new CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable>[uris.length];

for(int u = 0; u < uris.length; u++)
  mrs[u] = ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse(uris[u])).build();

CompletableFuture.allOf(mrs).handle((notUsed, throwable) -> {
    if (throwable != null) {
       throwable.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }

    try {
      for(int m = 0; m < mrs.length; m++)
        mrs[m].get(); // Do something, frist is andy.sfb, ..., last is shoes.sfb
    }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
      ex.printStacktrace();
    }
    return null;
});
```

Comment: says generic array creation .

Comment: Use lists instead of arrays and on `CompletableFuture.allOf(mrs)` you cast your list to an array.

Comment: can you give me some example on the above code @ManuelTS

Comment: Everyone not programming for only a week can alter the above code to lists. You have to do it on your own or at least post code wherein you try it.

Comment: @ManuelTS but in this case is not on the same ModelRenderable, is just a list/array of it, but you still have one for each sfb file. no?

Comment: @Canato, now I get what Rikesh Shrestha wants. But in his own code he uses single `ModelRenderable.builder()`s that is what lead me to arrays or lists, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

changing texture in ModelRenderable using CompletableFuture

```
CompletableFuture<Texture> futureTexture = Texture.builder()
          .setSource(this, Uri.parse(url))
          .build();
```

and call futureTexture in ModelRendrable

```
 ModelRenderable.builder()
    .setSource(this, Uri.parse("https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/3dmodels/andy.sfb"))

    .build()
    //.thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)

        .thenAcceptBoth(futureTexture, (renderable, texture) -> {
            andyRenderable = renderable;

            andyRenderable.getMaterial().setTexture("baseColor", texture);

        })
    .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
          Toast toast =
              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
          return null;
        });
```

call into Transformable node

```
TransformableNode andy1 = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
            andy1.setParent(anchorNode);
            andy1.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
            andy1.select();
```

Comment: how this answer is related with the question? The Question is "How to load ModelRenderable.builder() with multiple model?" and you answer is "changing texture in ModelRenderable"

Comment: its the same thing for model renderable like i used for changing textures by passing through url @Canato

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
List<RederableDefinition.Submesh> submeshes = new List<>;
submeshes.add(new RenderableDefinition.Submesh.setMaterial(Material material).setName(String name).setTriangleIndices(List<Integer> triangleIndices).build());

RenderableDefinition definition = new RenderableDefinition.setSubmeshes(submeshes).builder();
ModelRenderable.setSource(definition).build();
```

To be real I don't know exactly what expected from this, but Submeshes are the material (I hope what you mean by texture) and it is the **only** parameter that can be a list in a ModelRenderable.

A part from this your code look like you are trying to put 3 3D models on the same Model. Like draw 3 of them on the same place, would look weird and they would be one above another.
If you wanna give Andy shoes and maybe a background you need to make this already on a 3D models before or put then in different models.

Comment: i appreciate for you solution but i want to change texture for a model from outside for sfb model. I saw there was a method inside sfb file which call textures now i want to change the texture from code . THank you

Comment: @RikeshShrestha I didn't found the texture method on sfb file. I don't understood how change the Texture Programatically can be related with you main question about load multiple Models on same ModelRenderable.

Comment: @Canto i m able to change the texture in ModleRenderable . I m sharing the code